# When I reopen the program is everything fades in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code like that,

```
database = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\database.txt", "w")

print("Please type 1 if add a film")

enter = input("Enter: ")

if enter == "1":
    film=input("Please write a film name: ")
    database.write(film)
    database.close()
```

When I reopen the program is everything fades in txt file.How I do before writing what I write is saved under :)

Comment: This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) can be useful it has a table with all the different modes `a`, `w` and so on.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`a` mode](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open).

```
database = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\database.txt", "a")
```

The `w` mode will truncate the file when you open it (rewriting the file), while this will append to the end of the file.

To append into a new line, simply:

```
if enter == "1":
    film=input("Please write a film name: ")
    database.write(film + "\n") #\n is the newline character
    database.close()
```

Comment: Right it's work thanks but how i save under for example i write blabla and i reopen program i write blablabla result is blablablablabla

Comment: @Emek you need to add a newline character (/r/n on windows)